# Why do my network adapters do not show IP addresses when bridged?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bridge

I've set up an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine with two network adapters.

- eth0 (bridged adapter) - 192.168.0.105
- eth1 (NAT) - 10.0.3.15

I have performed ping commands to ensure everything is fine:

```
ping -I eth0 www.cnn.com
PING turner.map.fastly.net (185.31.17.73) from 192.168.0.105 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 185.31.17.73: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=29.6 ms

ping -I eth1 www.cnn.com
PING turner.map.fastly.net (185.31.17.73) from 10.0.3.15 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.3.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Since I would like eth1 to be able to access Internet through the eth0 adapter, I have bridged them based on [this](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) Debian tutorial.

Now the command `ifconfig` shows me the following:

- br0 - 10.0.3.16
- eth0 (bridged adapter) - No IP
- eth1 (NAT) - No IP

I can ping CNN like this:

```
ping www.cnn.com
PING turner.map.fastly.net (23.235.43.73) from 10.0.3.16 br0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 23.235.43.73: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=26.6 ms
```

but can't ping with the individual interfaces anymore.

Why does it happen? How can I be sure that I can now indeed access the Internet via eth1?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? “Accessing the Internet via `eth1`” isn’t really a thing.

Comment: @DanielB - I would like to share the Internet (eth0) to eth1 which will be connected to another device later.